# return value from nested $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-function

I need to run multiple $.get functions to several different php scripts and I was wondering if I can do it all in one generic function and just return the data. My plan was to do something like:

```
var companyName = 'Google';

var customers = get('Customers', companyName);
var vendors = get('Vendors', companyName);

function get(table, variable){
    $.get('http://www.mysite.com/phps/get'+table+'.php', {company: variable}, function(data){return data});
}
```

However, this does not work because it is in a nested function. Is this possible (easily) or am I going to have to do the $.get one at a time?

Comment: Asynchronous code requires that you bring the code to the result instead of returning the result to the code.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: In your console is displaying some javascript error? `$.get()` is defined? Quoting @Mike Brant: "What do you mean by it does not work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in Javascript functions are first class citizens, so rather than return a value, you would probably do best sending a function:

```
var companyName = 'Google';

var customers, vendors;

get('Customers', companyName, function(data) { customers = data; });
get('Vendors', companyName, function(data) { vendors = data; });

function get(table, variable, success){
    $.get('http://www.mysite.com/phps/get'+table+'.php', {company: variable}, success);
}
```

This is a poor example since it does not handle exceptions etc. But it should give you an idea on the flexibility provided to you. The key is to remember that functions are the building block of the language and what gives it power.

If you really want to stick with the method you are using **(I don't recommend)**, you could add one additional function... **(I really really don't recommend)**.

```
var companyName = 'Google';

var customers, vendors;

get('Customers', companyName, customers);
get('Vendors', companyName, vendors);

function get(table, variable, results){
    $.get('http://www.mysite.com/phps/get'+table+'.php', {company: variable}, function(data){ results = data});
}
```

Doing this would result in you losing the ability to change how the experience is handled based on the call result. Perhaps you want a select box disabled until the call completes and it is populated or perhaps you want to perform something special when a call fails. Using functions are a better approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your second example doesn't really make sense. JavaScript doesn't have pointers that can be dereferenced, so when you pass `customers` and `vendors`, you're really just passing the current value `undefined`. The assignment in the callback is happening to the local `results` variable *(parameter)*. The first example is a little better, but still isn't what a person would do since the assignment to those variables will likely happen long after the local code tries to use the variables. It would be more clear if your callbacks just directly used `data` instead doing the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery 1.5, [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) will return a `jqXhr` object, which implements the promise interface:

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise

Which can be used like this:

```
function yourMultipleGetFunction(success, error) {

    var jqXhr1 = $.get('url', data);
    var jqXhr2 = $.get('url2', data2);

    $.when(jqXhr1, jqXhr2).then(success, error);
}

yourMultipleGetFunction(function(data1, data2){
     //handle the objects returned from the get requests
}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //something went wrong, handle the error here
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for me or not. The code I showed was very simplified. I actually have about 40 different functions that would need to utilize the same get function, passing a couple variables into that function. Currently, each function just has it's own .get, I was just wondering if it would be easier to have one get function that they could all utilize. Looks like it is going to be more work to do it that way.

Comment: @TylerMortensen how then can you say that will not work if you have not tested whether it will work? As it showed in `function get (table, variable) {...});` will probably work, but it depends on you start to realize something.

Comment: If you don't have to do any specific parsing of the AJAX data, then you're good to go with promises; when they all are fulfilled (you'll know that with `$.when`, pointed by @Johan), you may continue with your app logic.